# Rails generators not loading for engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-engines

I'm working on an engine that was generated from rails 3 and now when I attempt to run the generators from Rails, it asks me to generate a new project.

It's evident that is not able to find the structure that is required for rails to invoke ActiveRecord, but I have no clue how to patch that

`rails g migration adding-active-boolean-to-types-and-statuses`

produces this:

```
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]                                      # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
                                                         # Default: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby
  -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]                              # Path to some application template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
      [--skip-gemfile], [--no-skip-gemfile]              # Don't create a Gemfile
  -B, [--skip-bundle], [--no-skip-bundle]                # Don't run bundle install
  -G, [--skip-git], [--no-skip-git]                      # Skip .gitignore file
      [--skip-keeps], [--no-skip-keeps]                  # Skip source control .keep files
```

I've tried adding the specific path and got the same results:

`/usr/bin/rails g migration adding-active-boolean-to-types-and-statuses`

Comment: use rails g migration AddingActiveBooleanToTypesAndStatue

Comment: Thanks @widjajayd, but I got the same result.

Comment: make sure you in working folder for example you working in my_apps then you should cd my_apps

Answer (score 2):

Solved:

the reason was that the project for some reason was missing a `bin/rails` folder.

Had to generate a new engine and copy/change the file to point to the right engine folder.

This is the content of it just if anyone needs it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# This command will automatically be run when you run "rails" with Rails 4 gems installed from the root of your application.

ENGINE_ROOT = File.expand_path('../..', __FILE__)
ENGINE_PATH = File.expand_path('../../lib/engine', __FILE__)

# Set up gems listed in the Gemfile.
ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path('../../Gemfile', __FILE__)
require 'bundler/setup' if File.exist?(ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'])

require 'rails/all'
require 'rails/engine/commands'
```